# Boxplot a dataframe column by date

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe of all tweets about a sporting event.  The tweets are arranged by date and now include a polarity rating using the afinn sentiment library.

What I'd like to do is create a matplotlib boxplot chart for each day in the range.  Unfortunately, I'm a coding newb, and I'm stuck.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

boxplot_maker = lambda x: plt.boxplot()
#creating a function that I will run against a specific column in the df

Event_df["P Score"].map(boxplot_maker)
#using the .map function and my boxplot maker to the column in question
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  I get the following error:

```
TypeError: boxplot() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

Comment: Guessing, that changing `boxplot_maker = lambda x: plt.boxplot()` to `boxplot_maker = lambda x: plt.boxplot(x)`
Could help. 
But if you provide more information about `Event_df` one could tell you more.

Comment: Event_df contains all of the Tweets, Days, and P scores in columns.  My end goal is to create a box plot of the P scores for each Day.  In other words, what is the pscore boxplot for all tweets on Day 1, Day 2, Day 3, etc....  Does that make sense?

Comment: Tip: make up some small fake data that is structured the same as your real data so we can see *exactly* what you are working with. The first step to debugging should be looking at documentation, but the second step should be making a [mcve].